# group particular position of string in a string array

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I want to group particular position of string in a string array.

Example:

```
string[] arr = {"DENVER01TECHNOLOGY",
                "DENVER02TECHNOLOGY",
                "DENVER01TECHNOLOGY",
                "DENVER0103TECHNOLOGY",
                "DENVER01TECHNOLOGY"};
```

I want to group the array based on the position at 7th and the length 2. ie a text between Denver and technology.

How can I achieve in C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var query = arr.GroupBy(i => i.Substring(6, 2));
// consider also using "DENVER".Length instead of 6
```

Usage:

```
foreach (var g in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine(g.Key);
    foreach (var item in g)
        Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Comment: OP misled you to write 7. He actually meant 7th position char, thus, 6 would be appropriate